# jQuery undo with multiple remove();

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the function to always remember the sequence of the last `removed` `.items` so that I may `undo` as many items that were removed before the `undo timeout` occurs?

I want to be able to quickly `remove` all `.items` and then press `undo` to replace all three, one by one where pressing the undo button replaces the last removed item.

Currently I can only replace the last removed `.item`.

```js
var undo = false;
var remove;
var timeout;
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*DELETE*/
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-times', function() {
    if ($('.item').hasClass("temp_deleted")) {
      $('.item.temp_deleted').remove();
    }
    remove = $(this).parent().parent();
    var undo_time = 10000;
    remove.animate({
      height: "0px"
    }, 200, function() {
      $(this).addClass('temp_deleted').hide();
    });
    function_undo(remove, undo);
    //undo
    $('.undo').addClass('active');
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.undo').removeClass('active');
      if (undo === false) {
        $('.item.temp_deleted').remove();
      }
    }, undo_time);

  });
  /*UNDO*/
  $('.undo div').click(function() {
    undo = true;
    function_undo(remove, undo);
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  });
});

function function_undo(remove, undo) {
  if (undo == true) {
    remove.css('height', 'auto');
    remove.show();
    remove.removeClass('temp_deleted');
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid
}

.actions span.fa-times:hover {
  color: #fe4444;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="undo">
  <div>
    <span class="fa fa-undo"></span> Undo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Save them in an array. When you remove it, `push` it in the array. When you want to undo something, `pop` it out.

Comment: It looks like somewhere in there you're actually removing the dom elements `if ($('.item').hasClass("temp_deleted")) {
      $('.item.temp_deleted').remove();
    }` Nothing to restore after that

Comment: @NoobTW that's a good idea. How would I structure that out?

Answer (score 2):

As I said, you can save them in an array. When you remove it, `push` it in the array. When you want to undo something, `pop` it out.

And by the way, as @LexJacobs said, don't `remove` it. just `hide` it.

Not sure if this is what you want. But I'm trying to structure this out.

```js
var undo = false;
var timeout;
var arr = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*DELETE*/
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-times', function() {
    if ($('.item').hasClass("temp_deleted")) {
      $('.item.temp_deleted').hide();
    }
    remove = $(this).parent().parent();
    var undo_time = 10000;
    remove.animate({
      height: "0px"
    }, 200, function() {
      $(this).addClass('temp_deleted').hide();
    });
    function_undo(remove, undo);
    //undo
    $('.undo').addClass('active');
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.undo').removeClass('active');
      if (undo === false) {
        $('.item.temp_deleted').hide();
      }
    }, undo_time);
    arr.push(remove);

  });
  /*UNDO*/
  $('.undo div').click(function() {
    undo = true;
    var remove = arr.pop();
    function_undo(remove, undo);
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  });
});

function function_undo(remove, undo) {
  if (undo == true) {
    remove.css('height', 'auto');
    remove.show();
    remove.removeClass('temp_deleted');
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid
}

.actions span.fa-times:hover {
  color: #fe4444;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span> 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span> 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span> 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="undo">
  <div>
    <span class="fa fa-undo"></span> Undo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would want to remove the item from the DOM after the timeout function (when the info dialogue disappears, remove from DOM). That way if the undo action is ignored, the item is completely removed.

Comment: And if you're going to really remove it without letting user undo, you can just call `arr.shift()` in to remove the oldest one in the array.

Comment: Just do something like `if(arr.length > 5) arr.shift();` or `setTimeout(() => {arr.shift();}, 10000);`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm a beginner with arrays so I'm not sure how to implement this.